# Is it possible to copy as text array value in Visual Studio debugger until specified level of nesting?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have a C++ array with about 1300 elements in it, each element is a structure with a nested structure that contains id as integer. I wanted to find possible duplicates of specific ids with a simple text editor in a form of textual data. When I'm copying the array item itself, it doesn't copy its children as well, just a minimal info for the array itself shown by NatVis, if I select array alongside with its values, it still doesn't copy needed info because `id` field is nested one level deeper in a structure. The only way I could reach desired field is to expand array's item value and copy that but expanding ~1300 elements each one by one is so time consuming and there's seemingly no way to do it in a bulk fashion. May be there's some command in debugger to copy array value as text, e.g. 3 levels deep?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just modify the program to dump this info into a file?

Comment: It's a rare case and a memory dump is only what I have for the actual problem. I think if I have a ready-to-inspect state and can inspect data I'm interested in so that there should not be technical limitations to do that

Comment: Probably I can dump it in a debugging session so there's no need to modify code and push it into production, it's a process that will take a lot of reviews, approves and integrations to a needed branch. Not an option for me at all